# App Store Connect - Change revise the metadata

Tags: ios, app-store

Apple rejected my app and I have to revise the metadata to resolve the issue.

It says:

> Since your App Store Connect status is Metadata Rejected, we do NOT require a new binary. To revise the metadata, visit App Store Connect to select your app and revise the desired metadata values. Once you’ve completed all changes, reply to this message in Resolution Center and we will continue the review.

But I'm not able to find the page to revise the metadata.

Please help me.

Comment: Go to App Store Connect, choose My Apps, pick the one that wants new information, select the version, add or edit what you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem in multiple instances usually with rejected descriptions of permissions to access different phone features such as:

- location (`NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription`)
- camera (`NSCameraUsageDescription`)
- microphone (`NSMicrophoneUsageDescription`)
- etc.

In fact you **can't** specify these in AppStoreConnect web UI. You need to add/change them in the app's `Info.plist` that also contains `CFBundleDisplayName` and submit a new binary.